# How do I use the params on my browser url on axios GET request

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Currently, I have been able to get the data into my component using

```
let {id} = useParams();
```

And when I call

{id} within my component, I get the id from the browser,s url. I however need it to enable me fetch data from my db

I have tried

```
const getData = () => {
     axios.get(`/API/joindiscussion/` + {id}, {
     //do something
     }):
}
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS API route: `/API/joindiscussion/:id`

Passed in react: `<Router path="/exmple/:id" element={<Example />} />`

Example component used:

```
const id =useParams()


const getData = () => {

    axios.get(`/API/joindiscussion/${id}`, 
    {
        // do something
    });
}
```

OR

NodeJS API route `/API/joindiscussion?id=123`

```
const getData = () => {
    axios.get(`/API/joindiscussion?${id}`, 
    {
        // do something
    });
}
```

This above concept in **ES6 JS**

Comment: This resolved my challenge. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check your API and how it takes the id ( I'm assuming you're confused between the param and query method ).

If the API takes the id in param format, ( like : `/API/joindiscussion/1234` where 1234 is the id) then your code should be

```
axios.get(`/API/joindiscussion/` + id,
```

If the API takes the id in query format ( like : `/API/joindiscussion/?id=1234` where 1234 is the id ) then your code should be

```
axios.get(`/API/joindiscussion/?id=` + id,
```

comment if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look like this:

```
let param = useParams()
axios.get(`url/${param.id}`).then(response => {
    // do something with the response
})
```